# Настроить верно перенаправления по всему сайту

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, seo

Подскажите, на многих сайтах. Взять к примеру ютуб, взять любую страницу, хоть с get параметрами (через '?'). Дописать свой параметр, то есть какой бы параметр не был вписан, то есть если url не соответствует странице, ютуб автоматом делает как я понимаю 301, перенаправляет на правильный юрл.

При этом, целевая страница, содержимое ее не меняется.

Как сделать похожий алгоритм проверки, как так реализовать проверку. У каждой страницы есть свои get параметры, ключи и значения разные + пользователь может вставить или поисковый робот перейти по некорректному юрл...

Не писать же в каждом модуле свой алгоритм проверки...???

Comment: Вставлять canonical, вроде как некорректно. Очень хочется, чтобы было так как на ютубе, а html canonical на второй так сказать фронт...

Comment: ютюб так делает только с малым количеством шаблонных URL, скорее всего проверяет их по нескольким шаблонам. Если у вас шаблонные URL - проверять их можно даже на уровне http-сервера. С произвольными URL можно делать только при генерации canonical-URL. Если текущий URL не совпал с canonical URL, тогда делать редирект. Правда зачем это всё на произвольном сайте я не совсем понимаю.